# What kind of paint primer can be sanded without peeling off

Tags: paint, plaster, patching-drywall, primer, priming

What kind of primer (paint) can be sanded after it is dry?

I painted a large object made from plaster of paris. I used latex-based primer. There were some lumps and bumps the day after the primer dried..

When I tried to sand the bumps off, the paint peeled off of the plaster like it was some sort of large white rubber party baloon.

What kind of primer will stick to bone dry plaster of paris and not peel off when sanded?

Comment: What do you mean by "bone dry"? How long ago was the object made?

Comment: Plaster is tricky, not only it absorbs a lot, but also it has a dusty surface. Latex will not work as well as oil based. Use vacuum cleaner before painting.

Comment: This seems like it's an art question, not a construction question, so have a look at this query: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how+to+prime+plaster+of+paris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use shellac-base primer.

Look for those exact words on the label. It says right on the label that it's good on unpainted plaster (and a multitude of other surfaces). It contains no water but uses alcohol as the solvent. A second coat (if needed) can be applied in just a few minutes. I've used it and it's sandable with no issues. You'll find it in the stain blocking primers section of your favorite paint retailer.

Hint: Do not use a foam applicator; the alcohol will make it swell and fall apart. If you intend to use a quality brush and clean it after use, you'll need denatured alcohol.